# Dajaxice not found on production server

Tags: ajax, django, ubuntu, django-staticfiles, dajaxice

I have a Django 1.4 project, running on Python 2.7 in which I'm using [Dajaxice](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) 0.5.4.1. I have set it up on my development machine (Windows 7) and everything works perfectly. However when I deploy my app to production server (Ubuntu 12.04) I get 404 error for `dajaxice.core.js` file and cannot resolve this problem no matter what. Production server works with exactly the same versions of all software.

My project structure looks like this:

```
/myproject
/myproject/myproject-static/ <-- all the static files are here
/myproject/myproject-static/css/
/myproject/myproject-static/img/
/myproject/myproject-static/js/
/myproject/templates/

/myproject/myproject/
/myproject/main/
/myproject/app1/
/myproject/app2/
/myproject/app3/
etc.
```

I was following the Dajaxice installation steps [here](http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) and put everything in its place (in `settings.py`, ˙urls.py`and`base.html` files).

My `settings.py` file has also these values:

```
from unipath import Path
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/myproject-static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_ROOT.child('myproject-static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'dajaxice.finders.DajaxiceFinder',
)

DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX = "dajaxice"
DAJAXICE_DEBUG = True
```

I have an `Alias` directive in my `django.conf` file which looks like this:

```
Alias /myproject-static/ "/path/to/myproject/myproject-static/"
```

I did `collectstatic` on my production server and got all static files collected within few folders in the root of my project. So, now when I look at my deployed web site, I can see that CSS is properly applied, JavaScript is working fine and navigation around the site works as intended. Everything is fine except Ajax is totally broken since `dajaxice.core.js` is never included.

My project folder structure after collecting static looks like this:

```
/myproject
/myproject/myproject-static/ <-- all the static files are originally here
/myproject/myproject-static/css/
/myproject/myproject-static/img/
/myproject/myproject-static/js/
/myproject/templates/

/myproject/admin/ <-- folder created with 'collectstatic' command
/myproject/css/ <-- folder created with 'collectstatic' command
/myproject/dajaxice/ <-- dajaxice.core.js is located here
/myproject/django_extensions/ <-- folder created with 'collectstatic' command
/myproject/img/ <-- folder created with 'collectstatic' command
/myproject/js/ <-- folder created with 'collectstatic' command

/myproject/myproject/
/myproject/main/
/myproject/app1/
/myproject/app2/
/myproject/app3/
etc.
```

Am I doing something completely wrong with my static files here?
What else should I try to fix this simple error?

Comment: hi, i am having a similar problem, did you fix yours in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Have you check if as the rest of the assets, `dajaxice.core.js` is inside your `static/dajaxice` folder? If not, the issue could be related with a miss configuration of the `STATICFILES_FINDERS`, check [Installing dajaxice again](http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-dajaxice)

Another usual issue with collectstatic and dajaxice is to run the first using `--link` Are you using this option?

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Jorge, thanks for answer! I changed my folder structure a bit and edited my original post accordingly. I didn't use `--link` option when I was collecting static files. Also, `dajaxice.core.js` is after collecting located in the root of my project in the folder `dajaxice`˙. I tried to explain it little bit more in my original post.

Comment: I maybe forgot to mention that I did check the provided link for installing dajaxice, and I'm pretty much sure that everything is on it's place. As I mentioned already, everything works on development server (Windows 7) but it fails when I deploy it on production server...

Answer (score 1):

I spend several hours grappling with this problem.  It was crazy because everything worked great on my dev environment, but not on the test server even though all the dajax and dajaxice settings were on a common base settings file.  I never got it to work using the standard route.  But this is a very easy fix:

1) Download dajaxice.core.js into whatever static directory pleases you.  You can find the js in your the dajaxice directory in your project root:

project/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js

In my case, I put the file in static/js alongside all my other js libraries.

2) On your web page, replace this:

```
{% dajaxice_js_import %}
```

with a normal, everyday link to the js library.  In my case:

```
<script src="/static/js/dajaxice.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Unfortunately, this patch only works for developed code.  If you usedo it in the development environment, new dajaxice code will be registered in the original project/dajaxice/ location and so the file will have to be copied to static after any new code is developed.